# How to navigate to directory by using last access time in powershell?

Tags: powershell

How to navigate to directory by using last access time in powershell?

By using the below command am only getting the Directories, But am not able to navigate to particular directory.

```
Get-ChildItem E:\ -Recurse -Directory | where{$_.LastAccessTime.(Get-Date)-10 }
```

Comment: Your query may return multiple directories - how will you determine which one to navigate to?

Comment: Hi,

What do you try to do with ".(Get-Date)-10  "  ?

Comment: You can't navigate to a particular directory, because your `Where-Object` filter is broken (it always evaluates to `-10`), so you're always getting a list of all directories. Fix your filter so that you get only the one directory you're interested in, then open it with the Explorer (`& explorer $_.FullName`).

Comment: Maybe `… where{$_.LastAccessTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-10) }`?

Comment: Maybe. We were trying to not spoon-feed a solution, though.